# Hide Google Map info window when map is moved with Swift

Tags: swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

So with my app, I'm displaying a custom info window on a GMS Marker. This info window takes up the top half of the screen and I don't want it moving with the Marker. So I want to hide the info window as soon as the map has moved. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make your `UIViewController` conform to `GMSMapViewDelegate` and then implement one of the methods listed here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/protocol_g_m_s_map_view_delegate-p
I guess the first one (`mapView:willMove:`) would work for you. I would use a print statement (or breakpoint) to check, whether the method is triggered as expected. To hide the current info window, you should be able to set `mapView.selectedMarker = nil`.
To sum up, your code might look like this:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    //declare your map, etc.
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // setup your map
    }
}

extension ViewController: GMSMapViewDelegate {
    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, willMove gesture: Bool) {
        if gesture { //The map was moved by the user
            //mapView.selectedMarker = nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So I just got a chance to test the code, it works, but there's an issue. When the marker is first tapped, the marker is brought to the middle of the screen, so it moves. This causes the Info Window to dismiss pretty much straight away. What could be done to fix this? The issue can be seen here: https://im4.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-4-3796cee6e0f3.gif

Comment: You could make use of the ```gesture``` parameter (see my updated answer).